# How to change window icon in electron after browser is open?

Tags: javascript, windows, icons, electron

I don't know if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask.

After my electron app opens a browser window and is displaying some icon in the taskbar and in its title bar for the window, can I change one or both of those icons *while* the browser is open? I suspect the answer is a hard no, but I thought it'd be cool if I could make it react in some way.

The search terms I came up with were mostly leading me to answers for how to change the icon *before* the window is open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `win.setIcon('/path/to/icon.png');` to change the window icon.

[`setIcon` Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winseticonicon-windows-linux)

Comment: @jadraptor No problem :), if my answer was helpful please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the icon completely from the titlebar? I don't want any icon